# Setup a project with Composer by using custom repositories and packages

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I am trying to setup a composer project that will enable me to setup my own framework and pulling out any given dependency stored in github private repos.

First some prerequisites:

1. I don't want to add code to packagist.
2. I want to make sure my vendor folder is as clean as possible.

---

Framework composer.json

```
{
    "name": "mycompany/myframework",
    "description": "YET another Framework",
    "type": "project",        
    "repositories": [
        {
          "type": "package",
          "package": {
             "name": "mycompany/system",
             "version": "0.0.2",
             "type": "library",
             "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/mycompany/system.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
             }            
          }
       }
   ],
   "require": {                
       "mycompany/system": "0.0.2",
       "mnsami/composer-custom-directory-installer": "1.1.*"        
   },    
   "license": "proprietary",
   "authors": [...],      
   "extra":{
       "installer-paths":{}
   }
}
```

---

mycompany/system composer.json

```
{
    "name": "mycompany/system",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "utility belt xD"
}
```

The code for the class in PHP ( from mycompany/sytem ) has the following structure:

```
namespace MYCOMPANY;
//this file name is called utils.php
//adherence to PSR-4 is assumed
class utils  {

}
```

**My goal is:**

I want to tell composer that it should create the following structure :

vendor \ MYCOMPANY \ utils.php ( not vendor \ mycompany \system \utils.php )

Later on, I want to be able to add more repositories like this and store them under MYCOMPANY as well. The framwework will work around this setup.

Custom installation is handled by [mnsami/composer-custom-directory-installer](https://github.com/mnsami/composer-custom-directory-installer)

I'm guessing I should keep, by rule of thumb, the different packages in their own directories, but, since there is no risk of overwriting because other files will have a different naming convention.

**Edit**
Can this be done?
If so, how?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's your exact question here? What have you tried so far to make this work? And yes, this is perfectly possible by the core functionalities of Composer

Comment: Additional hint about that Installer: I've never heard of it, but the last code changes are four years old. Maybe you want to overthink if you really want to use it

Comment: @NicoHaase sorry about that. I was asking how to do it. My attempts resulted in the vendor folder containing mycompany/system and not mycompany as intended. Is it possible? Which changes I must do in order for this to order? The 'alias' configuration is the nearest feature from composer but I don't think that's the answer for it. I've read elsewhere that the module should be named mycompany/mycompany for composer to assume the same name, but other modules can't have that name and I don't want to code different modules in the same repository.

Comment: @NicoHaase that installer was a test. I am currently reading the custom installer features of composer in order to check how they work, but I rather not using them, unless this is a last resort.

Comment: Why do you care about where the files are stored? It's common that Composer uses a multi-level structure within the `vendor` folder - that's the only way you can have **multiple** packages from the same `MYCOMPANY`  namespace

Comment: @NicoHaase i guess it's me wanting to have a clear file organization. But you are right. After some hours of messing around, I have to accept this way on how composer organizes the files. I'm my older projects I have each "package" on it's own folder according, much like composer, but I wanted to put them on the same folder. I will close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of work and following on @NicoHaase's reply in the comments, I gave up on this issue.

I was trying to make a clean folder where I would put all the different classes from different repos, but composer just doesn't work that way.

I hope this will help others that want the same thing.